# How do I block host name instead of just IP?

Tags: iptables, ip, hosts, blocking, deny

I was wanting to block a list of specific hosts, specifically so my server has no access to them at all. I tried using host2ip and entering the result into IP tables , but the IPs don't seem to lead to the site and I can still access the domains clearly.

How can I block say, 'bad.example.com' like I can on Windows with the HOSTS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're on some kind of *nix since you mention IPTables.  You can use the [/etc/hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file in a similar fashion to the windows hosts file.

However, adding a proxy like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is another option that may make managing block lists easier.

Comment: May sound weird, but I think I love you! Thank you.

Comment: Great, you can show me the love with an upvote and by checking answer! ;)

Comment: Had to wait 10 minutes to accept, hehe. There's your points.